# Export query results from Google Cloud Spanner to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I want to export my query results to Google Sheets. Is there some way to do it directly or using AppScript in Google Sheets.

Comment: The gcloud tool can help with this. Please see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451273/how-to-export-google-spanner-query-results-to-csv-or-google-sheets

Comment: @RoseLiu Thanks, Will check it out. Can we somehow do it using AppScripts in Google sheets

Comment: This is written in some other answer, below is the link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451273/how-to-export-google-spanner-query-results-to-csv-or-google-sheets

Comment: I'm 99% sure that there is not a native Spanner --> Apps Script connector

Answer (score 0):

Right now it’s not possible to export from Google Cloud Spanner directly to Google Sheets through Google Apps Script.

One way to do it is as [@RoseLiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9393857/rose-liu) commented, using [@RedPandaCurios solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53451860/8889821).

Another possible workaround could be to use Dataflow. You can export the Google Cloud Spanner database as a .csv file to Google Cloud Storage with Google Cloud Dataflow, then you import the .csv file to Google Sheets.

Dataflow has already available a template to export from [Cloud Spanner to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-templates#cloudspannertogcstext). Once the job is finished, you can download from Storage the .csv file through the [Console](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-java) or using the API.

Comment: @JesseScherer I guess a good option would be launching the Dataflow job from a Google Cloud Function (as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48601579/1308883)), and from AppsScript just send the HTTP request that triggers the function itself using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). The issue with this solution is that we are adding more and more products to the solution: GCF, Dataflow with templates, GCS, Sheets API...